# WPF datacontext binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I am working on a very simple example which should be very simple. I am just binding a Listbox, in my xaml, to an observablecollection. However I can not set my datacontext correctly.

```
<Window x:Class="TestThis.MainWindow"
<-- Just deleted some code here to make it look better -->  
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestThis"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Presenter}">
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"></ListBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Over d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Presenter}" it says "The name "Presenter" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:TestThis"   (TestThis is the project name). When I bind to my List box to my ObservableCollection, obs, it can therefore not bind to it.

The code for my Presenter class:

```
namespace TestThis
{
public class Presenter
{

    public Presenter()
    {
        _obs.Add("hy");
    }
    ObservableCollection<string> _obs = new ObservableCollection<string>();

       public IEnumerable<string> Strings
{
    get { return _obs; }
}

}
}
```

In the codebehind there is nothing more than the default, InitializeComponent().

UPDATE:
Recompiling the code fixed the datacontext problem

Comment: Is the TestThis namespace in a different assembly as the main assembly?

Comment: Aside from the obvious that obs should be a public property, have you tried recompiling? The Xaml Designer only updates the possible classes of a namespace after recompiling

Comment: Yes! Recompiling fixed it.